# OpenSeadragon navigator

Tags: javascript, openseadragon

I have a main window that contains a paper, using openseadragon i have a navigator to it, in order to view the state of zooming current view as shown in the picture.

in this image i have the navigator in the left-bottom, and it has the red rectangle, now the problem is when changing the view in the main window, part of the red rectangle disapears, in some cases all of the red rectangle disapear.

I tried to so many ways, but the framework seadragon overrides my changes.  
**is there any way in the openseadragon framework that set the max position to the rectangle?**

Comment: The red rectangle is minimap of viewer it would show how much portion of image is visible in viewport.

Comment: ok, but i need this rectangle to be always inside the minimap, in some cases the rectangle will be misleading because it will be outside the minimap (hidden).

Comment: I think setting visibilityRatio to 1 might help you.

Comment: Are you saying sometimes the red rectangle is outside of the navigator even when the viewer is showing content? Sounds like it might be related to https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1302